# citing from a review

Tags: citations

I'm writing my first proposal for M.Sc. , meanwhile, I keep reviewing many papers and tracking sources of citation, I noticed that some authors cite from review introduction while others cite from review conclusion. Does it mean that I can cite from any part in review paper as long as the cited information is by the sound of the review author (when he/she doesn't talk about a certain research nor cite from any) wherever it can be found in the review sections ??
thanks

Comment: Cite and reference...

Comment: so its ok then .. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> some authors cite from review introduction while others cite from review conclusion. Does it mean that I can cite from any part in review paper...?

**Yes**: You can cite any aspect of a paper. Albeit, you should avoid citing a secondary source (i.e., when a paper cites another, cite the original source,* rather than that paper). It is sometimes useful to cite a particular aspect of a paper, e.g., [Section 3, 1] or [Theorem 7, 2], so that readers can find specific aspects of papers to which you are referring.

<sup>*Do not cite the original source without sufficient consultation.</sup>

Comment: In some fields it is also ethically-required that if you cited a primary source you found in a secondary source, your citation look like "XYZ-primary-source, cited in ABC-secondary-source". This both acknowledges the work of the review author, and makes it easier for future readers to have access to what you were looking at. In other fields - please consider it even if it's not a requirement.

Comment: @einpoklum Do you really mean _if you cited a primary source you found in a secondary source_? It would surely imply that almost every citation is secondary. A slightly weaker statement that adds the requirement _without looking at the secondary source_ holds across many fields.

Comment: I meant that if you read XYZ's book or paper, which cites ABC, then you shouldn't just cite ABC with no mention of XYZ.

Comment: @einpoklum Can you give some exemplar fields? It seems like a bizarre methodology (to me), since many papers are discovered via another and recording this trail seems rather burdensome (and in some cases it may become problematic, e.g., with multiple authors, over the duration of a research career, ...)

Comment: In my experience, it's like that in legal scholarship / legal rulings (at least in some countries).